# Apply radiobutton color using styled-components in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

In the Material UI documents, they provided sample code to show how one can change the color of a Radiobutton.

```
const GreenRadio = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: green[400],
    '&$checked': {
      color: green[600],
    },
  },
  checked: {},
})(props => <Radio color="default" {...props} />);
```

I would like to replicate this with `styled-component` instead i.e. `const StyledRadio = styled(Radio)` but I am not too familiar with the syntax such as the ampersand and the dollar sign - how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using styled components with MUI, the CSS is applied to the `root` class of the component. If you need to apply a more specific style, then you'll need to target the relevant class. In this case, you'll need to target the `.Mui-checked` class:

```
const StyledRadio = styled(Radio)`
  color: ${green[400]};
  &.Mui-checked {
    color: ${green[600]};
  }
`;
```

The MUI docs are really good in that they list the CSS classnames for each component. If you visit the [API docs for the Radio component](https://material-ui.com/api/radio/#css), you'll see the `.Mui-checked` class listed there (under the 'Global Styles' column).

Here's a working example in Code Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/styled-components-9pewl

Answer (score 2):

Here's the appropriate styled-components syntax:

```
const GreenRadio = styled(Radio)`
  color: ${green[400]};
  &.Mui-checked {
    color: ${green[600]};
  }
`;
```

[image: Edit Radio custom color styled-components]

Related documentation: https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes